# Page expired issue with back button and wicket SortableDataProvider and DataTable

Tags: datatable, wicket

I've got an issue with SortableDataProvider and DataTable in wicket.

I've defined my DataTable as such:

```
IColumn<Column>[] columns = new IColumn[9];

//column values are mapped to the private attributes listed in ColumnImpl.java
columns[0] =  new PropertyColumn<Column>(new Model<String>("#"), "columnPosition", "columnPosition");  

columns[1] =  new PropertyColumn<Column>(new Model<String>("Description"), "description"); 
columns[2] =  new PropertyColumn<Column>(new Model<String>("Type"), "dataType", "dataType");
```

Adding it to the table:

```
DataTable<Column> dataTable = new DataTable<Column>("columnsTable", columns, provider, maxRowsPerPage) {
    @Override
    protected Item<Column> newRowItem(String id, int index, IModel<Column> model) {
        return new OddEvenItem<Column>(id, index, model);
    }
};
```

My data provider:

```
public class ColumnSortableDataProvider extends SortableDataProvider<Column> {  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Column> list = null;

public ColumnSortableDataProvider(Table table, String sortProperty) {
    this.list = Arrays.asList(table.getColumns().toArray(new Column[0]));
    setSort(sortProperty, true);
}

public ColumnSortableDataProvider(List<Column> list, String sortProperty) {
    this.list = list;
    setSort(sortProperty, true);
}

@Override
public Iterator<? extends Column> iterator(int first, int count) {
    /*
     first - first row of data
     count - minimum number of elements to retrieve
     So this method returns an iterator capable of iterating over {first, first+count} items
    */ 
    Iterator<Column> iterator = null;

    try {
        if(getSort() != null) {
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Column>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public int compare(Column c1, Column c2) {
                    int result=1;
                    PropertyModel<Comparable> model1= new PropertyModel<Comparable>(c1, getSort().getProperty());
                    PropertyModel<Comparable> model2= new PropertyModel<Comparable>(c2, getSort().getProperty());

                    if(model1.getObject() == null && model2.getObject() == null) 
                        result = 0;
                    else if(model1.getObject() == null) 
                        result = 1;
                    else if(model2.getObject() == null) 
                        result = -1;
                    else 
                        result = ((Comparable)model1.getObject()).compareTo(model2.getObject());

                    result = getSort().isAscending() ? result : -result;

                    return result;
                }
            });
        }

        if (list.size() > (first+count))
            iterator = list.subList(first, first+count).iterator();
        else
            iterator = list.iterator();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return iterator;
}
```

The problem is the following: 
- I click a column header to sort by that column.
- I navigate to a different page
- I click Back (or Forward if I do the opposite scenario)
- Page has expired.

It'd be nice to generate the page using PageParameters but I somehow need to intercept the sort event to do so.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a ton!!

Comment: The code will lay out more nicely here if you indent all the lines by four spaces or wrap it all in code tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know at a quick glance what might be causing this, but in order to help diagnose, you might want to enable debug logging for `org.apache.wicket.Session` or possibly more of the wicket code.

The retrieval of a page definitely involves calls to a method

```
public final Page getPage(final String pageMapName, final String path, final int versionNumber)
```

in this class, and it has some debug logging.

For help with setting up this logging, have a look at [How to initialize log4j properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly) or at the docs for [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html).